# Powerpoint SlideShows which show pages not in the slideshow

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2013, slideshow

As a PowerPoint 2003 user, I made extensive use of slideshows that - upon clicking on an item on the screen (i.e. a shape with a hyperlink) - jumped to page in the same PowerPoint file which is not in the slideshow (and is also not hidden). Once finished looking at that page, going 'next' (i.e. page down) would take you back to where you left off in the slideshow - perfect for an aside to the main thread of the presentation. I never had to do anything special to make this work, it was just the behviour you got, and it was perfect.

Now I am using PowerPoint 2013 and I discover that you are now not taken back to the place you left off in the slideshow if you do this, but instead you are taken to the start of the slideshow. This is clearly less than perfect.

My question is, how do I get it to operate as it did before. Is there a setting to get back the useful behaviour that 2003 had?

Comment: What you describe is not the way PPT has ever worked.  More likely you hid the slides, included them in a custom show, then set a link to the custom show from one of the other slides (and put a check next to Show and Return).

Comment: Errrr, no, I can assure you that this is exactly how PowerPoint 2003 works. I used the technique extensively over several different machines and many years. I have a huge stock of presentations using this technique. I think I would have noticed if I had created another custom show and linked to it! However, if your comment is suggesting that this is how it would work in newer versions of PowerPoint, then that would be interesting.  Could you expand on it as an answer please? After all, my question is about how to do it in new versions.

Comment: To avoid wheelspinning, it might be best for you to explain exactly how you accomplished what you did in 2003, since I'm apparently misunderstanding it. For example:  "clicking on an item on the screen"  What item?  How was it set up so that it " jumped to page which is not in the slideshow."  A page where?  Another PPT file?  A hidden slide within the main show?

Comment: Updated question with more details, let me know if there is anything more you require.

Comment: >>  jumped to page in the same PowerPoint file which is not in the slideshow (and is also not hidden).   Not sure I follow that one.  Is your MAIN show a custom show, one that doesn't include the slide you're jumping to here?

Comment: Yes, the slideshow being played is a custom show that does not contain all the slides in the deck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Steve's comments above, I was eventually able to work around this problem. Here's how you do it.

If you want to make an aside in a presentation, i.e. jump to a page not in your current custom slideshow (but still in the same presentation file), you need to create it as a custom show of its own, even if it is only a single page. Then instead of hyperlinking to the page directly, you hyperlink to the custom show. By doing this you enable the use of the "Show and Return" check box, which apparently only applies to custom shows now (whereas in 2003 it was the default behaviour when hyperlinking to any page).

So to get the same behaviour as you have in PowerPoint 2003, create all your hyperlinked pages as single page custom shows and link to them instead. A pain, a huge increase in the number of custom shows per file, but it does work!